# std::marker::Unpin is not satisfied

Tags: rust, async-await

I'm trying to get the futures try_join_all feature to work and I'm a bit stuck. My code is as follows:

```
use crate::Client;
use futures::future;
use std::boxed;

const SQL_EXTENSION: &str = "sql";

type ExecuteFileFuture = boxed::Box<dyn future::Future<Output = Result<(), postgres::Error>>>;

pub async fn run_migrations_in_path(
    path: &str,
    client: &mut Client,
) -> Result<(), postgres::Error> {
    let sql_files = files::by_extension(path, SQL_EXTENSION);
    let transaction = client.transaction().await?;
    let migrations: Vec<ExecuteFileFuture> = sql_files
        .iter()
        .map(|file_path| boxed::Box::new(client.execute_file(file_path)) as ExecuteFileFuture)
        .collect();
    future::try_join_all(migrations).await?;
    transaction.commit()
}
```

When I attempt to run this code I get the following errors:

> ```
> error[E0277]: the trait bound `dyn core::future::future::Future<Output
> = std::result::Result<(), tokio_postgres::error::Error>>: std::marker::Unpin` is not satisfied    --> src/migrate.rs:19:26
>     | 19  |     future::try_join_all(tasks).await?;
>     |                          ^^^^^ the trait `std::marker::Unpin` is not implemented for `dyn core::future::future::Future<Output =
> std::result::Result<(), tokio_postgres::error::Error>>`
>     |     ::: /home/moon/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/futures-util-0.3.4/src/future/try_join_all.rs:126:14
>     | 126 |     I::Item: TryFuture,
>     |              --------- required by this bound in `futures_util::future::try_join_all::try_join_all`
>     |
>     = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `core::future::future::Future` for `std::boxed::Box<dyn
> core::future::future::Future<Output = std::result::Result<(),
> tokio_postgres::error::Error>>>`
>     = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `futures_core::future::TryFuture` for `std::boxed::Box<dyn
> core::future::future::Future<Output = std::result::Result<(),
> tokio_postgres::error::Error>>>`
>
> error[E0277]: the trait bound `dyn core::future::future::Future<Output
> = std::result::Result<(), tokio_postgres::error::Error>>: std::marker::Unpin` is not satisfied   --> src/migrate.rs:19:5    | 19
> |     future::try_join_all(tasks).await?;    |    
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::marker::Unpin` is not
> implemented for `dyn core::future::future::Future<Output =
> std::result::Result<(), tokio_postgres::error::Error>>`    |    =
> note: required because of the requirements on the impl of
> `core::future::future::Future` for `std::boxed::Box<dyn
> core::future::future::Future<Output = std::result::Result<(),
> tokio_postgres::error::Error>>>`    = note: required because of the
> requirements on the impl of `futures_core::future::TryFuture` for
> `std::boxed::Box<dyn core::future::future::Future<Output =
> std::result::Result<(), tokio_postgres::error::Error>>>`    = note:
> required by `futures_util::future::try_join_all::TryJoinAll`
>
> error[E0277]: the trait bound `dyn core::future::future::Future<Output
> = std::result::Result<(), tokio_postgres::error::Error>>: std::marker::Unpin` is not satisfied   --> src/migrate.rs:19:5    | 19
> |     future::try_join_all(tasks).await?;    |    
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::marker::Unpin` is
> not implemented for `dyn core::future::future::Future<Output =
> std::result::Result<(), tokio_postgres::error::Error>>`    |    =
> note: required because of the requirements on the impl of
> `core::future::future::Future` for `std::boxed::Box<dyn
> core::future::future::Future<Output = std::result::Result<(),
> tokio_postgres::error::Error>>>`    = note: required because of the
> requirements on the impl of `futures_core::future::TryFuture` for
> `std::boxed::Box<dyn core::future::future::Future<Output =
> std::result::Result<(), tokio_postgres::error::Error>>>`
> ```

I've been looking through forums etc but haven't yet been able to solve the issue. I'm hoping someone can shed some light as I'm not sure where the problem lies.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Try replacing `Box<dyn Future...>` with `Pin<Box<dyn Future...>>` and `Box::new(...)` with `Box::pin(...)`.

Comment: On migrating from futures 0.1 to futures 0.3, I was helped by swithching numerous Box::new() for Box::pin(). I strongly suspect that would help OP.